# Filter parameters to POST verify and place order request for Performance storage

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to do BPM and SoftLayer integration using Java REST client. On my initial analysis(as well as help form stack overflow),I found

Step 1) we to get getPriceItem list to have all IDs for next request.

```
https://username:api_key@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/2/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,item[keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]
```

and then do verify and place order POST call using respective APIs.

I am stucked on `Step 1)` as filtering here seems to be bit tricky. I am getting a json response of over 20000 lines.

I wanted to show similar data(just like SL Performance storage UI ) on my custom BPM UI . (One drop down to select type of storage, 2nd to show location, 3rd to show size and 4th would be IOPS) where user can select the items and place request.

Here I found, SL is something similar to this for populating the drop downs-

> https://control.softlayer.com/sales/productpackage/getregions?_dc=1456386930027&categoryCode=performance_storage_iscsi&packageId=222&page=1&start=0&limit=25

Can't we have implementation where we can use `control.softlayer.com` just like SL instead of `api.softlayer.com`?  In that case we can use similar logic to display data on UI.

Thanks 
Anupam

Answer (score 0):

Here, using the API, the steps for performance storage. For endure storage the steps are similar you just need to review the value for categoryCode and modify if it needed

you can get the locations using this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getRegions

you just  need to know the package of the storage e.g.

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/222/getRegions
```

then, you can get the storage size for that you can use the SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItems  or SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices methods and a filter e.g.

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/222/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}},"locationGroupId": { "operation": "is null"}}}
```

Note: We are filtering the data to get the prices whose category code is "performance_storage_space" and we want the standard price locationGroupId = null

then, you can get the IOPS, you can use the same approach like above, but there is a dependency between the IOPS and storage space e.g.

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/222/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices": { "attributes": { "value": { "operation": 20 } },  "categories": { "categoryCode": {    "operation": "performance_storage_iops" } },    "locationGroupId": {    "operation": "is null" } } }
```

Note: In the example we assume that selected storage space was "20", the prices for IOPS have an record called atributes, this record tell us the valid storage spaces of the IOPS, then we have other filters to get only the IOPS prices categoryCode = performance_storage_iops and we want only the standard prices locationGroupId=null

To selecting the storage type I do not think there is a method the only way I see is that you call the SoftLayer_Product_Package::getAllObjects method and filter the data to get the packages for endurance, performance and portable storage.

Just in case here an example using the Softlayer's Python client to order

```
"""
Order a block storage (performance ISCSI).

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi_OS_Type
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi_OS_Type/getAllObjects
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Location
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Filters
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Python
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Masks

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

# Values "AMS01", "AMS03", "CHE01", "DAL05", "DAL06" "FRA02", "HKG02", "LON02", etc.
location = "AMS01"

# Values "20", "40", "80", "100", etc.
storageSize = "40"

# Values between "100" and "6000" by intervals of 100.
iops = "100"

# Values "Hyper-V", "Linux", "VMWare", "Windows 2008+", "Windows GPT", "Windows 2003", "Xen"
os = "Linux"

PACKAGE_ID = 222

client = SoftLayer.Client()
productOrderService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order']
packageService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package']
locationService = client['SoftLayer_Location']
osService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi_OS_Type']

objectFilterDatacenter = {"name": {"operation": location.lower()}}
objectFilterStorageNfs = {"items": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_iscsi"}}}}
objectFilterOsType = {"name": {"operation": os}}

try:
    # Getting the datacenter.
    datacenter = locationService.getDatacenters(filter=objectFilterDatacenter)
    # Getting the performance storage NFS prices.
    itemsStorageNfs = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilterStorageNfs)
    # Getting the storage space prices
    objectFilter = {
        "itemPrices": {
            "item": {
                "capacity": {
                    "operation": storageSize
                }
            },
            "categories": {
                "categoryCode": {
                    "operation": "performance_storage_space"
                }
            },
            "locationGroupId": {
                "operation": "is null"
            }
        }
    }
    pricesStorageSpace = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    # If the prices list is empty that means that the storage space value is invalid.
    if len(pricesStorageSpace) == 0:
        raise ValueError('The storage space value: ' + storageSize + ' GB, is not valid.')
    # Getting the IOPS prices
    objectFilter = {
        "itemPrices": {
            "item": {
                "capacity": {
                    "operation": iops
                }
            },
            "attributes": {
                "value": {
                    "operation": storageSize
                }
            },
            "categories": {
                "categoryCode": {
                    "operation": "performance_storage_iops"
                }
            },
            "locationGroupId": {
                "operation": "is null"
            }
        }
    }
    pricesIops = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    # If the prices list is empty that means that the IOPS value is invalid for the configured storage space.
    if len(pricesIops) == 0:
        raise ValueError('The IOPS value: ' + iops + ', is not valid for the storage space: ' + storageSize + ' GB.')
    # Getting the OS.
    os = osService.getAllObjects(filter=objectFilterOsType)
    # Building the order template.
    orderData = {
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_PerformanceStorage_Iscsi",
        "packageId": PACKAGE_ID,
        "location": datacenter[0]['id'],
        "quantity": 1,
        "prices": [
            {
                "id": itemsStorageNfs[0]['prices'][0]['id']
            },
            {
                "id": pricesStorageSpace[0]['id']
            },
            {
                "id": pricesIops[0]['id']
            }
        ],
        "osFormatType": os[0]
    }
    # verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with a call to
    # placeOrder() when you're ready to order. Both calls return a receipt object
    # that you can use for your records.
    response = productOrderService.verifyOrder(orderData)
    print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to place the order. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```