# Dynamically Populating Locations on the basis of Storage Type

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am a beginner in Softlayer and we need to implement  block storage functionality provided by softlayer in an Application. We just need to make REST call to fetch the locations on the basis of storage type selected. I need to know relationship between Storage Type and locations. What method I need to call in REST API and object mask required for same.. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, do you want the relation between "network storage type" and locations when a new item is being created/ordered? or Do you want to get the list of items with locations filtered by "network storage type"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order a new “Network storage” and know what “locations” are available for this item, see these steps:

**1.**  The first that we need to know is the “package id” to use for this order.
The “package id” is very important to valid and verifies what kind of items, what locations are available at the moment to order network storage.

For example:

```
Storage Type: Endurance, the package to use is “240”
Storage Type: Performance, the package to use is “222”
```

To get all active packages, please review:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects

**2.**  Once we know what package to use, we need to get the valid `“item price ids”` according to `LOCATION`. The following request can help us:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/[package_id]/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,item[keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]

Method: GET

Where:
A price id with a locationGroupId = null is considered "A standard price" and the API will internally switch the prices for the customer. But we recommend to execute first the verifyOrder in order to see if the wanted order is ok (the fee can vary).
```

Reference: http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You

Also, this method can help you to get available locations for a specific package:

```
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getRegions
```

**3.**  Then you will able to order a new Network storage, please see:

> [API for Performance and Endurance storage(Block storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454059/api-for-performance-and-endurance-storageblock-storage)

Now, if you want to list the network storage of your account, please see:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage

This is an example, where the result displays properties like: “location” and “network storage type”.

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[storageType, billingItem[description,location[id,longName]]]
```

Using filters:

Filtering by network Storage Type: `“Endurance Storage”` or `“Block Storage (Performance)”`

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,nasType,storageType, billingItem[description,location[id,longName]]]&objectFilter={"networkStorage":{"nasType":{"operation":"ISCSI"},"billingItem":{"description":{"operation":"Endurance Storage"}}}}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getRegions method

It returns the valid locations for a package, each storage type belongs to an specific package (that is the relation you are looking for) to get the packages use http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects method

see this post for more information

[Filter parameters to POST verify and place order request for Performance storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623245/filter-parameters-to-post-verify-and-place-order-request-for-performance-storage)