# Relationship between storage package (iops/gb) and a storage type and location?

Tags: api, rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create `REST call` that will fetch data on the basis of selected  block storage type (`endurance, performance, portable storage`) and by selected a location for selected `storage type`. Then trying to gather a list of `"storage package"` which I see options like `0.25 IOPS/GB, 2 IOPS/GB, and 4 IOPS/GB`.

What would be the best way to dynamically get a list of available "storage package" given that I have storage type and location information?

What method should I use and what can be the filter ?

Please share an example of that filter.

Comment: Are you asking for suggestions of what the URLs may look like; e.g. /storage-packages?location=EU&storageType=endurance

Comment: @morsor   yes,  what method and object filter exist for same..?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've given you an example of the URL I would use - and the QueryParams act as a filter

Answer (score 0):

your question looks similar to this one [Filter parameters to POST verify and place order request for Performance storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623245/filter-parameters-to-post-verify-and-place-order-request-for-performance-storage)

I recomend you use the standard prices, because they are easy to fetch and they work in any datacenter. In another hand if you want the prices for a determinate location keep in mind that there is the posibility that the price do not exist, that is because the price only exists if it is different from the standard price. for more information see http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You

Also I recomend you read documentation to understand how the orders work and how to get the data you need for the orders.

here an example to order the endurance using the locations using Python (note: the filters for rest are the same), take a look at the filters currently they are looking for an specific value such as storge size if you want all the storage sizes just remove that part from the filter.

```
"""
Order a block storage (endurance) with snapshot storage space.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing/getAllObjects
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Location
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3
http://sldn.softlayer.com/node/274081
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Python
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Masks

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Values "AMS01", "AMS03", "CHE01", "DAL05", "DAL06" "FRA02", "HKG02", "LON02", etc.
location = "set me"

# Values: "0.25", "2", "4"
iops = "set me"

# Values "20", "40", "80", "100", etc.
storageSize = "set me"

# Values "0", "5", "10", "20", "40", etc.
# Remember that the values must not exceed the size of the configured storage size.
snapshotSize = "set me"

# Values "Hyper-V", "Linux", "VMWare", "Windows 2008+", "Windows GPT", "Windows 2003", "Xen"
os = "set me"

PACKAGE_ID = 240

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
productOrderService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order']
packageService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package']
locationGroupService = client['SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing']
locationService = client['SoftLayer_Location']
osService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi_OS_Type']

objectFilterDatacenter = {"name": {"operation": location.lower()}}
objectFilterStorageEnterprise = {"items": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_service_enterprise"}}}}
objectFilterFileStorage = {"items": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_block"}}}}
objectFilterOsType = {"name": {"operation": os}}
objectMaskLocation = "mask[locations]"
objectMaskIops = "mask[attributes]"


try:
    # Getting the datacenter.
    datacenter = locationService.getDatacenters(filter=objectFilterDatacenter)
    # Getting file storage prices.
    itemsFileStorage = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilterFileStorage)
    # Getting the item prices whose category is storage_service_enterprise.
    itemsStorageEnterprise = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilterStorageEnterprise)
    # Getting the SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing which contains the configured location.
    locations = locationGroupService.getAllObjects(mask=objectMaskLocation)
    for item in locations:
        for loc in item['locations']:
            if location.lower() == loc['name'].lower():
                location = item
                break
        if 'id' in location:
            break
    # Getting the IOPS item prices which are equals to the configured IOPS, and are valid for the configured location.
    # In case we did not get a location group for the configured location
    # we are going to search for standard prices.
    if 'id' in location:
        objectFilterLocation = {"items": {"description": {"operation": iops + " IOPS per GB"}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_tier_level"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "in", "options": [{"name": "data", "value": [location['id']]}]}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterLocation
    else:
        objectFilterNoLocation = {"items": {"description": {"operation":  iops + " IOPS per GB"}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_tier_level"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterNoLocation
    itemsIops = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter, mask=objectMaskIops)
    if len(itemsIops) == 0:
        # In case we got an empty list we try getting the standard prices
        objectFilter = {"items": {"description": {"operation": iops + " IOPS per GB"}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_tier_level"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        itemsIops = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter, mask=objectMaskIops)
    # Getting the storage space which are equals to the configured storage space, meet the requirements for the configured IOPS, and are valid for the configured location
    # In case we did not get a location group for the configured location
    # we are going to search for standard prices.
    if 'id' in location:
        objectFilterLocation = {"items": {"capacity": {"operation":  storageSize}, "prices": {"capacityRestrictionMaximum": {"operation": itemsIops[0]['attributes'][0]['value']}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "in", "options": [{"name": "data", "value": [location['id']]}]}}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterLocation
    else:
        objectFilterNoLocation = {"items": {"capacity": {"operation":  storageSize}, "prices": {"capacityRestrictionMaximum": {"operation": itemsIops[0]['attributes'][0]['value']}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterNoLocation
    itemsStorage = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    if len(itemsStorage) == 0:
        # In case we got an empty list we try getting the standard prices
        objectFilter = {"items": {"capacity": {"operation": storageSize}, "prices": {"capacityRestrictionMaximum": {"operation": itemsIops[0]['attributes'][0]['value']}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}}
        itemsStorage = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    # Getting the snapshot storage space which are equals to the configured snapshot storage space, meet the requirements for the configured IOPS, and are valid for the configured location
    # In case we did not get a location group for the configured location
    # we are going to search for standard prices.
    if 'id' in location:
        objectFilterLocation = {"items": {"capacity": {"operation":  snapshotSize}, "prices": {"capacityRestrictionMaximum": {"operation": itemsIops[0]['attributes'][0]['value']}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_snapshot_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "in", "options": [{"name": "data", "value": [location['id']]}]}}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterLocation
    else:
        objectFilterNoLocation = {"items": {"capacity": {"operation":  snapshotSize}, "prices": {"capacityRestrictionMaximum": {"operation": itemsIops[0]['attributes'][0]['value']}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_snapshot_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterNoLocation
    itemsSnapshot = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    if len(itemsStorage) == 0:
        # In case we got an empty list we try getting the standard prices
        objectFilter = {"items": {"capacity": {"operation": snapshotSize}, "prices": {"capacityRestrictionMaximum": {"operation": itemsIops[0]['attributes'][0]['value']}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_snapshot_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}}
        itemsSnapshot = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    # Getting the OS
    os = osService.getAllObjects(filter=objectFilterOsType)
    # Building the order template
    orderData = {
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
        "packageId": PACKAGE_ID,
        "location": datacenter[0]['id'],
        "quantity": 1,
        "prices": [
            {
                "id": itemsFileStorage[0]['prices'][0]['id']
            },
            {
                "id": itemsStorageEnterprise[0]['prices'][0]['id']
            },
            {
                "id": itemsIops[0]['prices'][0]['id']
            },
            {
                "id": itemsStorage[0]['prices'][0]['id']
            },
            {
                "id": itemsSnapshot[0]['prices'][0]['id']
            }
        ],
        "osFormatType": os[0]
    }
    # verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with a call to
    # placeOrder() when you're ready to order. Both calls return a receipt object
    # that you can use for your records.
    response = productOrderService.verifyOrder(orderData)
    print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to place the order. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```